# String Comparison?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences in string compare methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c)

Is there any difference between these methods?

```
string.Compare(s1, s2) == 0
s1.CompareTo(s2) == 0
s1.Equals(s2)
s1 == s2
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reflector:

```
public static int Compare(string strA, string strB)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.None);
}
public int CompareTo(string strB)
{
    if (strB == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(this, strB, CompareOptions.None);
}
```

So `CompareTo` has an additional reference check than `Compare`.

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

So `==` is exactly the same as `Equals`.
The difference between two `Compare` and two `Equals` is, you can pass `CompareOptions` argument to `Compare`, and it returns 0/1/-1. while `Equals` doesn't receive a `CompareOptions` argument, and it can tell you TRUE/FALSE only.