# String Comparison Troubles

Tags: c#

Let me start by saying that I have read up on my problem, specifically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801027/string-comparison) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp). My problem is a little different, however. I understand the differences between the different methods, but cannot get my code to run correctly for the life of me.

In part of my code, I have the comparison below. But the comparison always fails, and "Type is:leg" prints out.

```
if (String.Compare(timer.Type,"leg",true) == 0)
{
    timer.StopTime = DateTime.Now;
    // TODO Log into database here
    toRemove.Add(timer);
}
//Couple more conditions in here...
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to remove cycle timer of invalid type");
    Console.WriteLine("Type is:" + timer.Type);
//TODO: Log error
}
```

I also tried alternative methods, but none of them seem to work for me.

```
if(timer.Type == "leg" || timer.Type == "Leg") //Fails

if(time.Type.Equals("leg") || timer.Type == "Leg") //Fails

String type = timer.Typer; //Worth a shot...
if(type == "leg" || type == "Leg") //No luck
```

EDIT: More code has been requested, so here is the entire method.

```
private void stopFinishedTimers(AGVData agv)
{
    List<CycleTimer> toRemove = new List<CycleTimer>();

    foreach (CycleTimer timer in AllRunningCycleTimers)
    {
        if (agv.CurrentRFIDNumber == timer.CycleStopRfid)
        {
            if (String.Compare(timer.Type,"leg",true) == 0)
            {
                timer.StopTime = DateTime.Now;
                // TODO Log into database here
                toRemove.Add(timer);
                }
            else if (timer.Type.Equals("route") || timer.Type.Equals("Route"))
            {
                timer.StopTime = DateTime.Now;
                // TODO Log into database here
                toRemove.Add(timer);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to remove cycle timer of invalid type");
                Console.WriteLine("Type is:" + timer.Type);
                //TODO: Log error
            }
        }
    }
```

Where CycleTimers are a class containing a fields called type, accessed through a property.

Comment: Where does the CycleTimer come from ? is this one of your own classes ? Do you use some special framework ?

Comment: @JShell Thanks for your update. However still, the definition of `CycleTimer` is missing.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter `StringComparison.Ordinal` fixed it, thanks a million

Comment: @JShell had you provided executable code this issue would have been found immediately. Could have been `"lag" == "Lag"` or something simple like that.

Comment: @usr unfortunately that's just not realistic on my end.

Comment: @JShell that's just a 20 character code snippet. Just capture the problematic strings with the debugger and paste them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add my two cents:

The line `String type = timer.Typer` seems wrong because the property name is `Type` in most of your examples.  Also `if(time.Type.Equals("leg") || timer.Type == "Leg")` seems suspicious since you are referencing `time` and `timer` instead of the same variable both times.

Lastly, I *always* **always** use `StringComparison.Ordinal` when comparing strings in .Net because of  culture info and character set differences, etc.  I'm not sure if that could be an issue but see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

EDIT:

On a side note, `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Debug and put a break statement to see what timer.Type equates to, or put a Console.WriteLine(timer.Type.ToString())...  Could timer have gone out of scope?

or maybe change the test to timer.Type.ToString() == "Leg"

Comment: == doesn't work that well on strings, Equals() method is always better.