# C# string sorting '@' sign difference with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I faced with a problem that string comparison in C# works a bit strange:

```
"0".CompareTo("@") // is 1
```

And I'm very surprised with that because ASCII codes is next:

```
ASCII '@' // 64
ASCII '0' // 48
```

If I'm comparing chats or use String.CompareOrdinal everything fine:

```
'0'>'@' // false
String.CompareOrdinal("0","@") // -16
```

And in JS it works also as expected:

```
"0" > "@" // false - in Javascript
```

Next thing that C# code I can't change - it uses CompareTo.

But I need same sorting rules in Javascript.
I can't find any solution smarter than replace '@' sign with the '#' because it ASCII code less than zero:

```
ASCII '#' // 35
```

Maybe somebody can explain why:

```
"0".CompareTo("@") // is 1
```

Or suggest better workaround how making comparison the same in Javascript

Comment: `CompareTo` is pretty different to `CompareOrdinal`, you may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120154/what-is-difference-between-different-string-compare-methods (just a side note for reference)

Comment: The equivalent to `CompareTo` in C# is [`localeCompare` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare): `"0".localeCompare("@")` also returns `1`. I believe any language will compare letters by the values of their character codes, so it will be the same. In other words: There is no difference.

Comment: Can't you use equals?

Comment: Seems the right way is to use  [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). But important that in this case, I should use the same locale as the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not strange, it's culture specific. I'm not an expert in js but I guess that [localeCompare](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp) may help you.

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. But then I've to know server side culture.

Comment: Yeap, but if you don't know server side culture, no client-side code will probably be able to help you. Btw, using culture specific string comparison on the server is meh...

Answer (score -1):

`CompareTo()` will return `1` if the first value is meant to be sorted *after* the second value (in ascending order), according to its call to `String.Compare(firstValue,(String)secondValue, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)`, which would consider `0` to come after `@` in a sorted list for display, so you would have `@foo,  0foo, 1foo, afoo, Afoo, foo`.

In JavaScript, you can pass a function to `Array.sort()` that would mimic the behavior for the relevant C# culture.

Comment: The OP's main question is about what can be done in js, I guess.

Comment: This is true, however from OP's perspective, the first value (`"0": 48`) is *not* greater than the second (`"@": 64`) - hence the question.