# Why checking for null before comparing a value to a constant?

Tags: c#

Sometimes, a value must be checked for equality with a constant. In such cases, I've always seen the code like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    if (text == "Some text here")¹
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

In my case, I would rather write:

```
if ("Some text here".Equals(text))
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

After all, if `text` is `null`, `Equals` will return `false`, which is expected. The inversion of a constant and a variable feels strange, but is still understandable for a beginner, and avoids the `NullReferenceException` which would be thrown with `text.Equals("Some text here")`.

Am I missing something?

Why all source code I've seen use the syntax from the first example, and never from the second one?

---

<sup>¹ In real code, it would rather be a constant or a readonly field. To shorten the examples, I put the strings inline.</sup>

Comment: I can imagine it coming from the Java world where == checks on Strings against in-code literals return false (due to object reference checks), but in C# if you're just checking for equality you can do the == since the operator overload handles the null case just fine.  Your first example seems completely unnecessary.  Just do `if (text == "Some text here")`

Comment: You might also be interested in this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In such cases, I've always seen the code like this:

You're right to think that's odd and unnecessary, because it is. It's a completely superfluous `null` or empty check. Frankly, I'd admonish code like that in a code review.

```
if (text == "Some text here") {
    // Do something here.
}
```

is perfectly fine and that's what I'd use.

> Am I missing something?

No, you're not missing anything.

> Why all source code I've seen use the syntax from the first example, and never from the second one?

Because you're looking for love in all the wrong places?

Comment: Thanks for the useful information and for making me laugh.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with just this.

```
if (text == "Some text here")
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

There is no need to check for null/empty, since it won't be equal anyway.

If you wish to use the `Equals` method, there is a version that isn't sensitive to null values.

```
if (string.Equals(text, "Some text here"))
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your version is fine so long as you have a literal or something that you know will not be `null`.

If, on the other hand, you had

```
if (text1.Equals(text2))
```

then clearly you would need to defend against `text1` being `null`.

But I would stop using `Equals` here and use `==` which removes the need for the `null` check

```
if (text1 == text2)
```

Are you preferring to use `Equals` because of your Java roots?

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is in human nature, when you compare smth, you always compare "your" stuff against someone else. not the other way around, i think same natual thinking went to C# coding as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `if (text == "Some text here")`.  It's clear, concise, and fast.  The `IsNullOrEmpty` check you refer to might be a (most likely useless) micro-optimization.