# Difference between the different overloads of String.Compare

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

Concretely what is the difference between

- [`String.Compare(String, String, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) and
- [`String.Compare(String, String, CultureInfo, CompareOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190529.aspx)

I feel like that the second one offers [more options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) (comparison using any culture instead of only the current one or invariant one, ignore special characters, ignore the width of katakanas (!!) etc...) [than the first one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx). Both have been introduced it in .NET 2.0 so I guess it can't be a question of backward compatibility.

So what's the difference and when should I use the first one and when should I use the second one?

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp) and this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx), but I think they're dealing with a slightly different matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in the remarks for the second overload.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190529.aspx

*"The comparison uses the culture parameter to obtain culture-specific information, such as casing rules and the alphabetical order of individual characters. For example, a particular culture could specify that certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character, that uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way, or that the sort order of a character depends on the characters that precede or follow it."*

The other overload just uses the default culture.