# StringComparison vs CompareOptions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, culture

*After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652851/difference-between-the-different-overloads-of-string-compare) I'm still confused :*

```
 string s1 = "hello";
 string s2 = "héllo";
```

The difference thing here is the accent/culture.

The result of the following code is `False`.

```
Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

But Im using *invariant* culture  , so it should treat é as e.( default is English ,no?)

it seems that I have to go all the way to use

```
String.Compare(String, String, CultureInfo, CompareOptions)
```

like

```
  string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) //true
```

But , my current culture is `he-IL` so I have no CLUE why it is working.

so :

- I can't understand when the `CompareOptions` didn't work although I used `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` ( <sub>and please don't reference me to the msdn page , cause I've already read it and I don't fully understand their explanation</sub> )
- In simple words , when should I use each overload ?
- Doesn't *[nonspacing combining characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx#memberList)* is a culture thing ?

Comment: `InvariantCulture` is basically a non-changing English useful for stuff like serialization or config files, but not for comparisons.

Comment: @sixlettervariables thanks. but if you think your answer made me understand those question i asked, you're wrong....:-)...(and what do you mean by _non-changing English_)

Comment: Whether `é` and `e` are the same or not is very Culture dependent. There is no reason for InvariantCulture to support a specific view here.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a comment and it does offer salient information relating to your question, so no need to be mean about it.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423377/what-is-the-invariant-culture and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492799/difference-between-invariantculture-and-ordinal-string-comparision are almost duplicates and combined probably answer your question.

Comment: @Pete do you see the smily  at the end ?

Comment: @Pete: I took no offense, being blunt is perfect in this case. I'm working on an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion with `InvariantCulture` is pretty common. The *best* use for this is when you are persisting data to and from a file and do not care about a given culture's oddities (such as `,` as a decimal separator or spelling flavor with a 'u').

It has limited use in comparisons, especially when you need culture specific behavior. It may not seem obvious on face value, but comparing e with an acute accent to be the same as e without one...well that is situation dependent.

Aha! Situation dependent you say.

Looks like a job for a *culture specific* overload. Anytime you know which culture you are using, you should pass that culture along.

In this case, you would like .Net to ignore diacritical marks (*p. ex. accent aigu*), hence you should also use an overload which accepts [`CompareOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx#memberList) (specifically as you noted `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace`).