# String Equals() method fails even though the two strings are same in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to compare whether two strings are equal or not in C# using the Equals() method of the string class. But even though both strings are same, my conditional check is failing.

I have seen that both strings are equal and also verified this at the http://text-compare.com/ site. I don't know what is the issue here...

My code is :

```
protected string getInnerParaOnly(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph currPara, string paraText)
        {
            string currInnerText = "";
            bool isChildRun = false;

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(currPara.OuterXml);
        XmlNode newNode = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        string temp = currPara.OuterXml.ToString().Trim();

        XmlNodeList pNode = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("w:p");
        for (int i = 0; i < pNode.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                XmlNodeList childList = pNode[i].ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode xNode in childList)
                {
                    if (xNode.Name == "w:r")
                    {
                        XmlNodeList childList1 = xNode.ChildNodes;
                        foreach (XmlNode xNode1 in childList1)
                        {
                            if (xNode1.Name == "w:t" && xNode1.Name != "w:pict")
                            {
                                currInnerText = currInnerText + xNode1.InnerText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              if (currInnerText.Equals(paraText))
              {
                  //do lot of work here...
              }
   }
}
```

When I put a break point in and go through step by step, watching each and every character, then there is a difference in currInnerText last index. It looks like an empty char. But I already used the Trim() function. This is the picture captured during the debug process.

What is the solution for removing the empty char or any other spurious characters at the end of the currInnerText string?

[image]

Comment: That is not your actual code (`Equals()` is not all lowercase in C#). Please paste your actual code.

Comment: There is clearly something you aren't telling us. The code you presented will definitely work if you are comparing two strings that are the same. We need to see more of your code.

Comment: Is paraText taken from a database?

Comment: If both `currInnerText` and `paraText` are `System.String` objects, as opposed to objects of a derived class, you can try using the `==` operator to compare them (`currInnerText == paraText`) and see what happens. This may give some additional insight into the problem.

Comment: is paratext  string or object

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp

Comment: please see my edited question for clear understanding of the code...

Comment: @aquinas.. it is a typo mistake.Actually it is a Equals()method

Comment: the strings aren't the same, there must be something a miss.

Comment: @Derek : I hope so, but i cann't able to find it out.. even though i checked in the url i mentioned

Comment: The only other way, which is abit ropey.. is to use Contains() rather than Equals()...

Comment: Please See my updated question.. it has a clue for our track :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try putting a breakpoint and checking the length. Also, in some cases, if the locale is not the same, the equals function does not result in true. Another method you could try(checking the length) is printing both like this ---string1---, ---string2---, this way, you could see if you have any trailing spaces. To fix this you can use string1.trim()

Answer (score 28):

Try this

```
String.Equals(currInnerText, paraText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank youuuu, you are life saverrrr

Comment: Or, to have case compared as well: `String.Equals(currInnerText, paraText, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 14):

In my case, the difference was different encoding of space character, one string contained non-breaking space (160) and the other one contained normal space (32)

it can be solved by

```
string text1 = "String with non breaking spaces.";
text1 = Regex.Replace(text1, @"\u00A0", " ");
// now you can compare them
```

Comment: You saved my life ;). Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I was reading one text from db and another creating in program and then matching two.

Comment: Similar issue for me... though was the '-' character (char 45) showing up as char 8211 when read from an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: Wonderful! But I think the @ in your searchStr should be removed.

Comment: @PixelHunter Thanks, maybe, however, I can't test it now!

Answer (score 8):

Before you call .Equals, try this:

```
if (currInnerText.Length != paraText.Length)
    throw new Exception("Well here's the problem");

for (int i = 0; i < currInnerText.Length; i++) {
    if (currInnerText[i] != paraText[i]) {
        throw new Exception("Difference at character: " + i+1);
    }
}
```

That should throw an exception if Equals returns false and should give you an idea what's going.

Comment: :thanks you for your cute tracking techniques...I will update u tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using characters that look like other characters, but are actually different, this can occur when using Reflection. Reflection boxes the values twice into new objects and `==` will compare by reference. Try using `object.Equals(currentValue, newValue)` instead.