# Efficient(?) string comparison

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string-comparison, processing-efficiency

What could possibly be the reasons to use -

```
bool result = String.Compare(fieldStr, "PIN", true).Equals(0);
```

instead of,

```
bool result = String.Equals(fieldStr, "PIN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

or, even simpler -

```
bool result = fieldStr.Equals("PIN", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

for comparing two strings in .NET with C#?

I've been assigned on a project with a large code-base that has abandon use of the first one for simple equality comparison. I couldn't (not yet) find any reason why those senior guys used that approach, and not something simpler like the second or the third one. Is there any performance issue with `Equals` (static or instance) method? Or is there any specific benefit with using `String.Compare` method that even outweighs the processing of an extra operation of the entailing `.Equals(0)`?

Comment: I disagree with Alex R., and think this should be duped to [Differences in string compare methods in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp) since that article is very mature and has excellent answers already.

Comment: Given links are helpful for anyone to get an understanding of string comparison in C#, i agree, but they by no means reflect my query? Please read the post first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't give immediate examples, but I suspect there are cases where the first would return `true`, but the second return `false`. Two values maybe equal in terms of *sort* order, while still being distinct even under case-ignoring rules. For example, one culture may decide not to treat accents as important while *sorting*, but still view two strings differing only in accented characters as unequal. (Or it's possible that the reverse may be true - that two strings may be considered equal, but one comes logically before the other.)

*If* you're basically interested in the sort order rather than equality, then using `Compare` makes sense. It also potentially makes sense if the code is going to be translated - e.g. for LINQ - and that overload of `Compare` is supported but that overload of `Equals` isn't.

I'll try to come up with an example where they differ. I would certainly say it's rare. EDIT: No luck so far, having tried accents, Eszet, Turkish "I" handling, and different kinds of spaces. That's a long way from saying it cant happen though.

Comment: Jon, that was a bit heavy you know! Except for the LINQ translation possibility part, it took me a while to grasp what you are talking about...whew

Comment: @NerotheZero: Cultural differences are like that, unfortunately - full of corner cases and things which seem odd.

Comment: Jon, I've edited the question a bit. Could that be anything to add something to your answer?

Comment: @NerotheZero: I think you should ask the people who wrote the code, if at all possible - if you're trying to express equality, then I'd use Equals. (And even if you were using `Compare`, it would me more idiomatic to write `== 0` than `.Equals(0)`.)