# using textbox data to check a radiobutton

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have a textbox that gets the gender value from database. Based on the textchanged event, the radiobuttons respond accordingly.

```
private void txtInvisibleGender_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtInvisibleGender.Text == "Female")
        rbFemale.Checked = true;
    else
        rbMale.Checked = true;
}
```

The problem is that when the data in textbox is Female, then why is the Male radiobutton being checked? It doesn't check based on the data from the textbox. How do I make this work?

Comment: show us the text of this txtInvisibleGender.Text

Comment: txtInvisibleGender.Text = read["Gender"].ToString();

Comment: try my answer. and always use equals for string comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `false branch` is always excecuting as your condition is never `true`.

```
if (txtInvisibleGender.Text == "Female")
    rbFemale.Checked = true;
else
    rbMale.Checked = true; // we are reaching here.
```

I suggest changing it to

```
if (txtInvisibleGender.Text.Trim().ToLower().Contains("female"))
    rbFemale.Checked = true;
else
    rbMale.Checked = true;
```

It's worth noting that the `if-else` will check male under all circumstances where `txtInvisibleGender` does not contain `"female"`. So typing `"foobar"` will check male.

I would change it to:

```
// "female" contains "male" so Contains() cannot be used!
if (txtInvisibleGender.Text.Trim().ToLower().Equals("female"))
    rbFemale.Checked = true;

if (txtInvisibleGender.Text.Trim().ToLower().Equals("male"))
    rbMale.Checked = true;
```

then if it's anything other than `"male"` or `"female"` it doesn't check anything.

Comment: even if I try another If statement for Male and also the Else-If, It doesn't work as it is supposed to..

Comment: See my updated answer. Change to txtInvisibleGender.Text.ToLower().Contains("female").

Comment: Yes I just tried... That worked! Can you please explain why my code didn't work? It was basically the same thing with the txtInvisibleGender.Text == "Female"

Comment: Your code didn't work because the text box did not exactly contain the string "Female". It might have had other characters like "/n" or the case was wrong. "Female" != "female"

Comment: Trim() removes whitespace, ToLower() removed uppercase and Contains() says that the string has the string "female" somewhere within it.

Comment: I'm not so sure the bottom code is correct.  If you call `.Contains("male")` on the string "female", then it will return true, and check the male radio button.  I think `.Equals` would be better.  That, or it needs to be `else-if`

Comment: oh yeah! female contains male! Thanks RyanWH:)

Comment: @SamLeach seen. Thanks for explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You should user string.Compare instead of ==.

it means that your textbox doesn't have this value, atleast not in the same casing. Try this

```
private void txtInvisibleGender_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(string.Compare(txtInvisibleGender.Text.Trim(), "Female", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)     
    rbFemale.Checked = true;
else
    rbMale.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: @SamLeach You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same

Comment: @SamLeach i have updated my answer and read this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp