# How can I compare two string values for equality?

Tags: c#

I need to find the klas of 5TIF2 and dont now how to compare it to the class

```
private void BtnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Leerling oleerling = new Leerling();
    oleerling.MijnId = TxtId.Text;
    oleerling.Voornaam = TxtVoornaam.Text;
    oleerling.Naam = TxtNaam.Text;
    oleerling.Klas = TxtKlas.Text;

    if (oleerling.Klas = "5TIF2")
    {
        LstLeerlingen.Items.RemoveAt(2);
        LstLeerlingen.Items.RemoveAt(3);
    }
    else
    {
        LstLeerlingen.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        LstLeerlingen.Items.RemoveAt(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `==` equality operator in `if` statement, `=` is used to assign value.

Comment: The question seem to really be, "how to compare strings", since `oleerling.Klass` and `"5TIF2"` are probably both strings. See programming guide: [How to compare strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)

Comment: `==` is usually fine, but if you need more control over the exact rules for the comparison then use `.Equals()` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-5.0 for details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences in string compare methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288/differences-in-string-compare-methods-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the operator `==` to check if a statement is true or false, instead you have used `=`, which is for assigning values.

You need:

```
  if (oleerling.Klas == "5TIF2")
```